# Calculate functions based on asymptotic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions, fourier-transform

Consider the function $\Lambda(k)$, which is an even function in $k$, and it has following conditions
For small values of $k$
$$\Lambda(k) \sim x_0^2$$
and for large values of $k$, the behaviour of the function
$$\Lambda(k) \sim \frac{1}{k^2}$$

In addition to these conditions $\Lambda(k)$ is an even function in k and $\Lambda(k) > 0 \;\;(\forall k \in \mathbb{R})$
From these conditions, we can possibly write series expansions about $k=0$ and $k=\infty$, as follows,

at $k=0$, series can be written as:
$$\Lambda(k) = x_0^2\left( 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n (kx_0)^{2n}\right)$$

On the other hand, at $k\rightarrow\infty$, the series can be written as,
$$\Lambda(k) \sim x_0^2 \left( \frac{1}{(kx_0)^2} +\frac{b_1}{(kx_0)^4} + O\left[k^{-6}\right] \right)$$

The question is:

**Can a general even function $\Lambda(k)$ be defined that satisfies these conditions, namely the limits as $k\to 0$ and $k\to \infty$?**

A particular example is
$$
\Lambda(k) = \frac{x_0^2}{1+(k x_0)^2}
$$
which can be written in the series form for $|k| < 1$ with $c_n = (-1)^n$.

PS: An additional note is that $\Lambda(k)$ is a Fourier Transform of a function $\Lambda(x)$.

Comment: Your second limit makes no sense.  What does it mean for $\lim_{k\to\infty} \Lambda(k) = \frac{1}{k^2}$.  You have $k$ as the limiting variable on the left, and as a constant(?) on the right.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thank you for pointing it out, I have edited it to make it more clear. Hope it helps.

Comment: That still makes no sense.  As $x \to \infty$, $kx \to \infty$ for any $k$.  Thus $$\frac{1}{4} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \Lambda(2x) = \lim_{x\to\infty}\Lambda(3x) = \frac{1}{9}. $$  This can't be right.

Comment: @XanderHenderson You're right! I am making a blunder somewhere, let me alter the question altogether.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I have modified the question substantially, does this make sense?